# Replacing array with matching key in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, filter

I'm trying to create a function which will replace array values with its matching object value. I've tried using `.filter`. However, it will not allow for duplicate values as seen in the example below.

Current code

```
        fetchInventory: async function () {
            await Object.entries(this.$store.state.inventory).forEach(([k, v]) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(v); i++) this.inventory.push(parseInt(k))
            })

            const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceCache'));
            const filteredItems = await items.list.filter(i => this.inventory.includes(i[0]));

            this.inventory = await filteredItems;
        }
```

Input
`var array = [1208, 1209, 1209]`

Current output

```
var output = [[1208, 'returned item'], [1209, 'returned item']]
```

Expected output

```
var output = [[1208, 'returned item'], [1209, 'returned item'], [1209, 'returned item']]
```

localStorage Object
[image: const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('priceCache'));]

Comment: Where are you using `array`?

Comment: On another note, Wonder if `await` is required in each of those lost two lines.

Comment: Try `[1208, 1209, 1209].map(e => [e, 'returned item'])`

Comment: Its coded in vue, in the first part I'm pushing values to data array, @User863 I like where your headed but 'returned item' is just placeholder, there are dynamic values for each number.

Comment: Where are you getting these dynamic values? Please provide all the relevant information so we can help you.

Comment: Can you put the exact input because from this `array = [1208, 1209, 1209]` you can very well map to get your desired output.

Comment: Added edit of the dynamic object im trying to filter out from my array

Comment: How is the object?

Comment: Is `array` the inventory?

Comment: yes it is @hev1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want `Array#map` and `Array#find`.

```
this.inventory = this.inventory.map(v=>[v, items.list.find(x=>x[0]===v)[1]);
```

Comment: @Shimsho No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't want `filter` to lose any of the values in `array` (`1209` here, for example)

So what you actually need is `map` first and then `filter`:

```js
var items = [1208, 1209] 
// inventory
var array = [1208, 1209, 1209] 
// filtered inventory
var output = array.map(i => items.includes(i) ? [i, 'returned item'] : undefined)
  .filter(i => i !== undefined)

console.log(output)

/** output:
(3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) [1208, "returned item"]
1: (2) [1209, "returned item"]
2: (2) [1209, "returned item"]
**/
```

Comment: Why not simply this?
`var array = [1208, 1209, 1209];
var res = array.map(i=> [i, "returned value"]);
console.log(res)`

Comment: Because he has to filter according to the inventory from the code he posted.

Comment: It's not very clear because they have just defined the input like this `var array = [1208, 1209, 1209];`